# Adding CKEditor to project without <script> tags in index.html

Tags: ckeditor, sapui5

I am developing an application with SAPUI5 and I need to have CKEditor in this application, but I cannot load CKEditor with a  tag like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/full/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

because the application is run by running Component.js file instead of index.html.

When I add CKEditor through sap.ui.define or jQuery.registerModulePath, i get the following error:

**"Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined"**

Has anyone had experience with something like this and can suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version is to use the [jQuery.sap.includeScript](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.includeScript) to include the script dynamically. You should do this in an initialization method (e.g. the `init` method of the component).

Also make sure that you wrap this call inside a "guard", i.e. a check to make sure that the library is not already loaded. You could either check if a ckeditor global variable is not set or you can check if a script tag with a predefined ID does not already exist.